# Sum value of output of template in Apache FOP

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP to generate a PDF document, and to display a certain value I have to iterate over a number of nodes to determine a *total price* value, then sum that value. So far I have a function that iterates over an array and then retrieves the intended value, but the issue occurs when I try to sum the results.

```xml
    <xsl:function name="foo:buildTotalValue">
    <xsl:param name="items" />

    <xsl:variable name="totals">
      <xsl:for-each select="$items/charge">
        <xsl:call-template name="getTotalPriceNode">
          <xsl:with-param name="itemParam" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($totals))" />
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template name="getTotalPriceNode">
    <xsl:param name="itemParam" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$itemParam/Recurrance = 'OnceOff'">
          <xsl:value-of select="$itemParam/TotalValue" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$itemParam/Recurrance = 'Monthly'">
          <xsl:value-of select="$itemParam/TotalValue * $itemParam/Months"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="0" /></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

I'm hoping that when I pass in foo:buildTotalValue with entries like this:

    <Charges>
      <Charge>
        <Recurrance>OnceOff</Recurrance>
        <TotalValue>50.00</TotalValue>
      </Charge>
      <Charge>
        <Recurrance>Monthly</Recurrance>
        <TotalValue>10.00</TotalValue>
        <Months>6</Months>
      </Charge>
    </Charges>
```

would return with the value 110.00, but instead I get the error:

```
Cannot convert string "50.0060.00" to double
```

I've tried adding a `<value>` or something in the templates and then using that as a selector for the `exsl:node-set` function but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Which processor are you using? You have tagged this as `xslt-1.0` but `xsl:function` requires XSLT 2.0+. OTOH, an XSLT 2.0 processor does not require `exsl:node-set()`. So you have a hodgepodge of versions. Likewise, it should not be necessary to have a function AND a named template for the same task.

Comment: Are you sure you use an XSLT 1 processor? `xsl:function` is only supported in XSLT 2 and later and there you would just use the expressive power of XPath 2/3 with e.g. `sum(Charge[Recurrance = 'OnceOff']/TotalValue | Charge[Recurrance = 'Monthly']/(TotalValue * Months))` and you don't need any iteration or function at all.

Comment: My mistake, got confused around the versioning.

Apache Fop 2.2, which supports xsl-1.1. 
For the actual transformation, we are using Saxon 9.8 which supports xslt 3.0

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, the problem with your function is that it builds a concatenated string of values returned by the called template, instead of a tree of nodes that can be converted into a node-set and summed.

Try changing:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$items/charge">
    <xsl:call-template name="getTotalPriceNode">
      <xsl:with-param name="itemParam" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

to:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$items/charge">
    <total>
      <xsl:call-template name="getTotalPriceNode">
        <xsl:with-param name="itemParam" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </total>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($totals))" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($totals)/total)" />
```

---

Untested, because (see comment to your question).

Comment: Have just attempted this, get the output of 0.  Its almost as if the <total> is being stripped out of the result

Comment: As I said, I haven't tested this. I don't see much point dwelling on it, because this is not a good approach, neither in XSLT 1.0 nor in XSLT 2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the suggestion from Martin from the comment - the xpath 2+ expression along the line of:

```
sum(Charge[Recurrance = 'OnceOff']/TotalValue | Charge[Recurrance = 'Monthly']/(TotalValue * Months))
```

which was able to achieve what I needed without the use of functions / templates / node-set (And in a lot less code)